# $\|u\|_{\infty}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{L_2}+\|u\|_{L_2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Under which conditions does

$$\|u\|_{\infty}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{L_2}+\|u\|_{L_2}$$

hold for some constant $C>0$?

Where $u$ satisfies $\sup_x x^b \partial^a_x u(x) \in L^\infty$ for all multiindices $a,b\in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ and $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: I think there is a typo in your inequality because it is equivalent to $C\|\Delta u\|\ge 0$.

Comment: Do you mean the $H^2$ norm on the left? If yes, then you can verify this using integration by parts (or what amounts to the same thing, divergence theorem). In particular, $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\right)^2\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{(\partial x^i)^2}\right)^2\,dx$. Or, barring a few constants, $\|D^2u\|_{L^2}^2=\|\Delta u\|_{L^2}^2$. Also, you’re assuming $u$ is Schwartz, so you can throw away all the boundary integrals.

Comment: ok… what I said gives you control of the $\dot{H}^2$ term. You can control the $\dot{H}^1$ part using a similar integration by parts (you can control this using $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2}$ and $\|u\|_{L^2}$). Anyway, once you establish the inequality, you can use a density argument to prove it for all $u\in H^2(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, it should be the supremumsnorm on the left...

Comment: On the whole space, this follows from taking the Fourier transform and Holder inequality as in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523375/estimate-involving-l-infty-norm-of-function-in-h2-mathbbr-cap-h-1/4523554#4523554

Comment: @LL3.14 thank you. This solves my problem

Comment: Also I thank the others for there help and sorry for the initial typo